# Why is "search application provider" eating 90% of my Android CPU?

Tags: applications, 2.3-gingerbread, search, htc-incredible-s

According to the "OS Monitor" app, the core "search application provider" is eating most of the CPU on my HTC Incredible S.

There are multiple log messages with the following error : "Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0 row 10845" where the row value keeps increasing followed by another error "not growing since there are already 10846 row(s), max size 2097152".

I have disabled all search plugins and reset the cache, is there anything I can do to stop the "search application provider" eating my CPU and degrading the performance of my other apps (these errors coincide with jerkiness and slowdowns in other apps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the 'search applications provider' has something to do with google's internal phone data / app search apk

Either way:

Have you tried going into:

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Google Search

Choose 'Clear Data' and also 'Clear Cache'.

Also there is an app in the list called: 'search applications provider' [linky](http://appaware.org/app/com.android.providers.applications/) , if your really struggling try uninstalling it. From the page linked it looks like other people have! (I've also read some other people back it up and freeze it with titanium backup ((i.e. it's like a safe uninstall)))

Comment: That did help for a while, but I've since unistalled a few apps, and the performance is back as expected. I'll keep an eye on it, but thatnks for the tip.